# Retrying webclient post with modification of the request

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

In my application I'm using an API that requires user to be authenticated. To authenticate I need to provide proper header with token value received from the API after sending proper POST with username and password.

Obviously I could run the `login` POST before every other call but I'd like to keep my code clean but, more important, cache the provided token (it's valid for some time after the login).

Therefore I wrapped my webclient in some service class like this:

```
private AuthenticationRepository authenticationRepository; // simple repository that keeps the String value of token

public <T extends APIResponse<?>> Mono<T> send(RequestData postRequest, Class<T> responseType) { // these are my custom domain classes
    return webClient
        .post()
        .uri(url)
        .header("authToken", authenticationRepository.getUserkey())  // obviously the first time it will return null
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(responseType)
        .doOnSuccess(throwWhenErrorReturned()) // therefore I need to throw some exception when API will return information that the request is unauthorized [btw it's returning HTTP 200...]
        .onErrorResume(handleError(postRequest, responseType));
}

private <T extends APIResponse<?>> Function<Throwable, Mono<? extends T>> handleError(RequestData request, Class<T> responseType) {
    return e -> {
        if (e instanceof RequestUnauthorized) {
            return loginUsecase.login(this).flatMap(loginResponse -> { // loginUsecase is just a mentioned webclient POST call with login/password
                final String token = loginResponse.getToken();
                authenticationRepository.setUserkey(userkey); // here I'm setting userkey in repository
                return send(request, responseType); // and this is my current 'poor' retry implementation
            });
        }
    };
}
```

As you can see I'm 'retrying' the POST request by calling again `send` method but I wonder is it possible to make it better using `Mono` API. I know there are `retry` and `retryWhen` methods but they do not allow me to change the request and add proper header. Once set to `null` is retrying with `null` everytime.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use `retryWhen` to resubscribe to the original publisher and execute request again. It will give you more control on retry logic

```
webClient
        .post()
        .uri(url)
        .header("authToken", authenticationRepository.getUserkey())
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(responseType)
        .onErrorResume(RequestUnauthorized.class, e ->
               loginUsecase.login(this)
                        .map(loginResponse -> authenticationRepository.setUserkey(loginResponse.getToken()))
                        .then(Mono.error(e)) // replay error to handle downstream
        )
        .retryWhen(
                Retry.backoff(10, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                        .filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof RequestUnauthorized) // retry on specific error
        );
    }
```

The better way to implement oauth flow for WebClient is to create `filter`, [Client Filters](https://spring.getdocs.org/en-US/spring-framework-docs/docs/spring-web-reactive/webflux-client/webflux-client-filter.html).

Spring Security provides some boilerplates for common oauth flows. Check [Spring Security OAuth2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.12.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2.html) for more details.

Here is an example of simple implementation of the client credential provider

```
private ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth(String clientRegistrationId, ClientConfig config) {
    var clientRegistration = ClientRegistration
            .withRegistrationId(clientRegistrationId)
            .tokenUri(config.getAuthUrl() + "/token")
            .clientId(config.getClientId())
            .clientSecret(config.getClientSecret())
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
            .build();

    var authRepository = new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistration);
    var authClientService = new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(authRepository);

    var authClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
            authRepository, authClientService);

    var oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authClientManager);
    oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(clientRegistrationId);
    return oauth;
}
```

then you could use it in the `WebClient`

```
WebClient.builder()
    .filter(oauth)
    .build()
```

Comment: In your solution you set a new token from a filter function `.map(loginResponse -> authenticationRepository.setUserkey(loginResponse.getToken()))`
and I don't like it because to my mind it is not a job of the client to set auth tokens in their repository. It should be enough just to call `refreshToken()` on the authRepository and all subsequent calls to it should return a new token. But I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: When I add a `block()` call to `refreshToken()` in order to wait for it and set a new token in the same method - I couldn't chain it in the main request's filter because of `block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-2`